# How to debug default cmdlets - Get-TfsWorkspace

Tags: powershell, debugging, tfs, powershell-cmdlet

What I tried:

When I try the cmdlet `Get-TfsWorkspace` with the `-path` parameter I am getting error:

> 'Unable to determine the current work-space based on the path XXXX'

Looking forward:

Can you please provide any other alternative where I can debug the cmdlets and see if there are any issues. I am sure the path and set up is correct but curious to know if any thing I am missing. This is one of the built in cmdlets not my cmdlets.

Comment: Please choose one relevant version or explain why you need your code to be compatible to 3 different versions of powershell.

Comment: Its an issue with the power tools. figured out. Thanks